# More memory in Nvidia GPUs?

Tags: opengl, opencl, nvidia, ati

is there a parameter that can be passed to the Nvidia OpenCL/OpenGL implementation to increase the amount of available memory? (Like GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE from Ati Stream)

Currently i can use about 512mb from the 1gb available on the graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of available GPU memory is fixed by the manufacturer, there is no way you can increase this amount programmatically but you can use host memory instead, consider the fact that it might be 10-100 times slower than your GPU's GDDR